# how to create a folder in sdcard programmatically that can be shown directly in windows and in the phone

Tags: android, directory, sd-card, mount, unmount

I created an android application in which it creates a folder that stores data, but I want it to be shown right away in windows when the usb is connected. right now, it can only be seen after i restarted the mobile device or mount and unmounted the sdcard. or is there even a way to mount and unmount the device programmatically?

someone recommends me this snippet
 `sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));`

but i can't seem to understand how to apply this code or if this is even applicable with my concern.

Comment: [This](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/how-to-create-sub-folder-in-sd-card.html) link will surely help you... Let me know if you still have the problem....

Comment: thanks for the link but that's what i have right now. my problem is it can't be shown in windows right away not until sdcard in mounted and unmounted.

Comment: Hmmm...For now you can take the user to the device's built-in Settings, till we can find your suitable solution..



   `Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MEMORY_CARD_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(i);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to launch a scan on the new files so that they can be seen from outside. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19934089/5232306)

```
// initiate media scan and put the new things into the path array to
// make the scanner aware of the location and the files you want to see
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] {path.toString()}, null, null);
```

PS: This question is a bit old but it is the first one I found when I got stuck... So, probably worth answering for the next ones !