# Android in programmatically created folder not showing in Desktop

Tags: android, directory

I creating a folder programmatically in android but it not shown in PC. I refer this answer ([Folder added in android not visible via USB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507789/folder-added-in-android-not-visible-via-usb)). It's solve my problem but in my PC this folder shown as webbing format.

MY code

```
public void createUsedFolserTOSDCard() {
    String IEPATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"EPaySlipGenerator"+File.separator+"Import Export";
    File file = new File(IEPATH);
    if(!file.exists())
        file.mkdirs();

    File file2 = new File(Global.DIR_PATH);
    if(!file2.exists())
        file2.mkdirs();

    String BACKUPPATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"EPaySlipGenerator"+File.separator+"Database Backup";
    File file3 = new File(BACKUPPATH);
    if(!file3.exists())
        file3.mkdirs();

    String PDFPATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"EPaySlipGenerator"+File.separator+"PaySlip";
    File file4 = new File(PDFPATH);
    if(!file4.exists())
        file4.mkdirs();

    // Show folder in PC
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] {file.toString(), file2.toString(), file3.toString(), file4.toString()}, null, null);
}
```

Show this folder in PC but in my phone it's show perfectly.

[image]

So, how can i solve this problem?

Comment: which format it should be?

Comment: All these are Folder not file. @Opiatefuchs

Comment: I don´t think that this is a programming related problem...Do You have any idea what "Webbing" means? I read only about adware...

Comment: No i have no idea about "Webbing". @Opiatefuchs

Comment: Than it is possible that You have any adware on Your machine....You should check it, look here: http://blog.mitechmate.com/webbing/

Comment: having same issue @JigarShekh   you have any solution