# Cannot create a file?

Tags: android, file

I have a problem with creating files in Android. I have followed [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html#java) tutorial, and wrote this method:

```
public File getStorageDir(String name) {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).toString();
        File file = new File(path, name);

        System.out.println(path);
        if (!file.mkdirs()) {
            System.out.println("Directory not created");
        }

        return file;
    }
```

Path variable prints  /storage/emulated/0/Documents, however if goes off and no such directory is created. I have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

permissions to manifest file. I have tried using file.getParentFile().mkdirs() but got same result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have an error ? If yes, add your log

Comment: `Android cannot create file` ??? I dont see you trying to create a file. Only a directory.

Comment: no errors... just nothing happens

Comment: which  android version are you installing the code

Comment: `I have added ...
permissions to manifest file.`. That is not enough for Android 6+ as you can read here in at least ten posts every week. Please read some hours stackoverflow pages tagged `android` and you will know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You use below code to create folder.

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                File.separator + "folderName");

        if (!folder.exists()) {
            success = folder.mkdirs();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

So turns out it was being created the whole time, just not visible in file explorer. I have fixed it with answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507789/folder-added-in-android-not-visible-via-usb). Final code looks like this:

```
public File getStorageDir(Context context, String name) {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getPath();
        File file = new File(path, name);

        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] {path}, null, null);

        return file;
    }
```

Thanks everyone for answers, hope this helps someone who faces same problem.

Comment: Well this function creates file in specified folder. I would say that it is something. And it solves problem with MTP protocol, as explained in linked post. No need to be so grumpy.

Comment: It does not create a file. Sorry.